# Using Python, how can I loop through a csv file and print each cell?

Tags: python, csv

I am uploading a csv file and would like to loop though the data and insert each cell into the database. Here is the python code:

```
import csv
@app.route("/uploadcsv", methods=['POST'])
def uploadcsv():
    myfile = request.files['file']
    r = csv.reader(myfile)
    headers = r.next()
    for row in r:
        print str(row[0])
        print row[1]
        print row[2]
        print row[3]
        print row[4]
        print row[5]
        print row[6]
        print row[7]
        print row[8]
        # put into database
        return "OK"
```

There are currently 3 rows in the csv file (many more later) and only the first row is printed, how can I print all the rows?

The csv file is:

```
first_name,last_name,email,phone,designation,company,industry,tag,created_at
john,smith,john@example.com,1234567,some company,some industry,some tag, now()
```

Comment: it's because of the return. take it out of the for loop

Comment: You are return "OK" before moving to the next row

Comment: That only has two rows and your for loop starts on the second row because of the `r.next()` call so it should only print one row. Still the return is your main issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce the indentation of the `return "OK"` statementby one level - as it is currently, it returns from `uploadcsv()` as soon as the first row has been printed, and not, as you intended, after the for-loop.

Comment: thank you to all! So simple. works fine now. I am a newbie to Python and I did not really understand indentation, so many thanks.

Comment: glad to help. On stackoverflow, please accept the correct answer by pressing the checkmark on the left.